# Match to the end of the string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, newline

Given a string and regex, how can I make sure it matches the entire string? That is, I don't want a newline to trigger the end of the match - I want it to match to the very end of the string.

Example:

```php
<?php
// simplified date pattern
$pattern = "/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}$/";
$d = "2014-01-05\n"; // OOPS - this will match
if(preg_match($pattern, $d)) {
    echo "This is a date string.";
}
```

Comment: What if first `trim` it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`D` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> D (PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY)
>   If this modifier is set, a dollar metacharacter in the pattern matches only at the end of the subject string. Without this modifier, a dollar also matches immediately before the final character if it is a newline (but not before any other newlines).

```
$pattern = "/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}$/D";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the multi-line pattern modifier `m` like this:

```
$pattern = "/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}$/m"; // note m at end after pattern
```

Comment: From OP: "That is, I don't want a newline to trigger the end of the match"

Comment: It doesn’t. Modifier `D` is necessary, see my answer.

Comment: modifier `D` is, in essence more specific than `m` and would suffice in the specific example given, but it would not suffice in a case where you had a newline character in the middle of the match that you are trying to make.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. OP wants a strict match, meaning any variation such as `2014/01/07` or `2014-01\n-07`, and from the example, `2014-01-05\n`, is supposed to fail. You're just making the match broader with the `m` modifier.

Comment: If I understand what Mike's saying, it's that if we wanted to match something like `"asdf\ng"` but not `"asdf\ng\n"`, then we'd need to use the pattern `/^asdf\ng$/mD`. That way it both matches past newlines and also doesn't treat them as an end-of-string. **However**, although you'd think it would work that way, a quick test on the CLI just showed me that including the `m` modifier undoes the behavior of the `D` modifier and **furthermore**, using `D` alone can match over multiple lines. Might be a bug in the implementation, because I would've expected `mD` to work.

Comment: @sjagr I understand that.  In the example given, if you use `m` modifier, would generate the proper no match condition, because `\n` would be the last character in the string and fail the end anchor condition.

Comment: @Mike Your previous comment that "modifierD [...] would not suffice in a case where you had a newline character in the middle of the match that you are trying to make" is false, at least in the current PHP regex implementation. You can try it yourself. EDIT: Also, regarding the comment you just posted, `preg_match("/^a$/m", "a\n") === 1`.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius It would certainly not work for this example case shown, but say the user had a string like `"2014-01\n-01"` that he wanted to match as date without regard to new line, he would need to use `m` modifier to match that data that is broken across lines.  I was trying to address the statement that "I don't want a newline to trigger the end of the match - I want it to match to the very end of the string." If the end of the string was on another line (which it is not for this example) then `D` would not have any effect.

Comment: I guess I looked more at the wording of the question than the example in trying to formulate my response.  Based on the example and the OP's acceptance of the `D` modifier approach, I don't think I was fully understanding what he was looking for.

Comment: @MikeBrant "he would need to use m modifier to match that data that is broken across lines" This is not true though. The `D` modifier works both for not treating ending newlines as end and also for catching newlines in the middle. (I didn't expect this behavior either, but that's what it does. It is a bit odd - the `m` is a subset of the `D` behavior.)

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Hmm that doesn't sound right, though I haven't tested thoroughly. I always perceived the inverse of what you said to be true.